# Javascript converts img src to invalid base64

Tags: javascript, image, base64, tampermonkey

I try to retrieve profile icons from web.whatsapp.com.  The source code explorer as well as with javascript retrieved img node shows me a regular static link to the image I want to get  (https:....)

[Image tag retrieved with javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ0tk.png)

Retrieving the correct src should be a trivial task but no matter if I use

```
image.src or image.getAttribute('src')
```

I always end up with the same base64 string for what ever picture I try to fetch. How do I extract the src of the image tag without it being converted into gibberish?

[Result of the image.src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Xjf.png)

This was done using tampermonkey on google chrome on a mac.

**Edit:** Additional info as per request:

```
<img src="https://dyn.web.whatsapp.com/pp?t=s&amp;u=4915786584978%40c.us&amp;i=1484932082&amp;ref=1%40%2FOBUmUFr2127pJ5jnyNl9BylFIWp6h2FiEm475nQg0gtYw%2FSf7tuwfp9&amp;tok=1%4016ljMAEqnFIwx%2FcEvV4mq6VdicCO59U5CXvI%2FDlEBR09UnXl5bHnAXdEBO3r3zPVMNP7W4g2BWMmNw%3D%3D" draggable="false" class="avatar-image is-loaded">
```

The base64 string does not start with an ';'. This was just part of my console debug. The plain content is shown below.

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```

Comment: Can you include text of `img` `src` at Question? Does `img` `src` actually begin with `;` character? Image links are generally not helpful in determining issue.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited to question to include the requested information.

Comment: How do you get `data URI` where `<img>` `src` is set to an external URL?

Comment: I hope this is the information you are looking for:  The javascript code can be found here: [https://jsfiddle.net/mo10m1L0/](https://jsfiddle.net/mo10m1L0/)  The img tag as seen in the image and the edit is retrieved by javascript using the following command.  var profileIconElement = conversation.getElementsByClassName('avatar-body')[0].getElementsByTagName('img');  calling profileIconElement.src gives back the

Comment: No `html` is included at jsfiddle?

Comment: It would have been hard to provide html, as the website contains private sensitive data, and the page itself is rather huge. Either way the problem solved itself after adding a small delay before executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that even though the javascript script waited for the execution until the image dom objects were created the src was not set yet. A small delay in the execution solved the issue